# What is the difference

Tags: java, android

```
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                image5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(image5.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

If I write like this, I can get information about button5's visibility and it makes a toast message.

```
 if(image5.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                image5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
```

But if write the code like that,  I can't get information about the visibility and there is no toast message. I need to learn the visibility outside of clickonlistener block. Can you help me? What do I need to do?

Comment: make a variable outside `clickonlistener`, and in `clickonlistener` assign visibility to it

Comment: Why you can't get visibility? `view.getVisibility()`. Also your code makes no sense, you're assigning to VISIBLE then checking if it is VISIBLE?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(image5.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                image5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
```

**Issue:** Issue is you are just making image5 visible based on the button click and there is no any action which would check whenever Image5 gets visible.

In first example, you are setting visibility and at the same time checking whether imageview is visible, if yes then showing toast message.

Which is not happening in the case of second example.

Comment: @MohammedAtif dude check the code again, he is setting imageview visibility based on the button click! He hasn't mentioned anything about button invisibility.

Comment: Yea, sorry my bad, his code formatting made it look like listener is inside if block, removed the comment soon after realizing the mistake though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different check to know `visibility` of `View`.

like below code:

```
if(image5.isShown()){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You can add above check in your click listener like below :

```
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                image5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               if(image5.isShown()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
            }
        });
```